# View full commands in ps output

Tags: terminal, ps, putty

When running `ps` with the `-f` option in PuTTY (to see the command corresponding to each process), lines which are longer than the terminal width are not fully visible (they are not wrapped on multiple lines).

How can I force line wrapping so that I can see the full commands (on multiple lines, if necessary) when running `ps -f`?

Comment: Not an answer, but if I run ps -f in shrinked terminal emulator, output is wrapped on multiple lines. What terminal are you using?

Comment: This could be a duplicate of:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159860/viewing-full-output-of-ps-command

Comment: @MatthewRock I use PuTTy here, do you think this is specific to it?

Comment: @Tonsenson Do we consider duplicates across Stackexchange sites ? Also, shouldn't this question belong to unix.stackexchange.com instead of stackoverflow.com ?

Comment: @fiddler - see if the answer from Tonsenson's link helps you. If so, the question should be considered inappropriate - posting your question title into google outputs Tonsenson's link as first result, so answer is easy to find.

Comment: @MatthewRock thanks for the advice.
Fiddler: I don't know. Maybe the question is older than the unix community. But have a look at the link and then we can talk about how we are going to proceed

Comment: @Tonsenson Yes, this can definitely be considered a duplicate.

Comment: @MatthewRock it is. This site started in mid-2010, IIRC. But we don't consider dupes across sites. Quoting that post in an answer here is perfectly fine by Stack Exchange standards. (Though Tonsenson could have tried to retain formatting.)

Comment: Then it's my bad. Initially I didn't see that answer was posted on SE, and [this article](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and maybe some Meta post I've read convinced me that posts that can be answered by simple google query aren't good questions.

Comment: @MatthewRock Shall I delete the question, then?

Comment: According to muru who's more experienced than me, I'd say no. If the answer from @Tonsenson 's link was helpful, then it'd be probably the best that he undeleted his answer.

Comment: Or just flag this as duplicate of said question?

Comment: @Tonsenson can't close as a cross-site duplicate.

Comment: @muru Shouldn't all these former linux-related questions somehow moved from stackoverflow.com to unix.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @fiddler ah, we can't migrate old questions without moderator intervention, and even then it's not recommended: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8004/should-we-migrate-old-questions

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you have a POSIX-conforming `ps` implementation, you may try

```
ps -f | more
```

Note that we¹ recently changed the behavior and if you have an implementation that follows POSIX issue 7 tc2, you may try:

```
ps -wwf | more
```

¹  <sub>We being the people who have weekly teleconferences to discuss the evolvement of the POSIX standard.</sub>

Comment: `ps -wwf` works just fine.

Comment: Note, this is the right answer for the questioner's case (`ps -f`), but others may prefer having `aux` in there as well, as in fibonacci's answer.

Answer (score 56):

For simplicity, try this:
`ps auxfww`

Comment: This worked! The accepted answer (of ps -wwf and ps -f) did not.

Comment: not working for me

Comment: Worked for me, I'm guessing it's because I'm on `PowerShell` and not on a putty or ssh terminal.

Answer (score 12):

I've probably found the answer for your question 
[on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159860/viewing-full-output-of-ps-command). In the words of [Dennis Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson):

> It is likely that you're using a pager such as less or most since the
>   output of ps aux is longer than a screenful. If so, the following
>   options will cause (or force) long lines to wrap instead of being
>   truncated.
>
> `ps aux | less -+S`
>
> `ps aux | most -w` If you use either of the following commands, lines
>   won't be wrapped but you can use your arrow keys or other movement
>   keys to scroll left and right.
>
> `ps aux | less -S`    # use arrow keys, or <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>)</kbd>, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd> and
>   <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>)</kbd>
>
> `ps aux | most`       # use arrow keys, or <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> (Tab can also be used
>   to scroll right) Lines are always wrapped for more and pg.
>
> When `ps aux` is used in a pipe, the w option is unnecessary since ps
>   only uses screen width when output is to the terminal.

(Note: this applies to non-embedded Linux, the `ps` utility on other Unix variants may work differently.)

Comment: @muru hope this is now looking better. Thanks for clearing all up!

Comment: And sorry for causing the mess.

Comment: Didn't cause any mess. It is a good think discussing about that stuff; I am still pretty new to SO (at least talking about my knowledge). So thanks for the input!

Comment: Your answer only applies to `/usr/ucb/ps` and even with this program you would need `ww` as `/usr/ucb/ps` limits the output width to 80 if the output is a pipe. For the POSIX standard ps, see my answer.

Comment: @schily This answer is perfectly correct for the usual `ps` command on non-embedded Linux, which is what a majority of readers here have.

Comment: But the OP did not set /linux as tag.

Comment: True. schily's commands are producing nothing for me. Where would they work??

Answer (score 7):

There is also another simple solution:

```bsh
echo "$(ps afx)"
```

When run in a command substitution like this, `ps` isn’t sending its output to a terminal, so it doesn’t limit its output to the terminal’s width.

Comment: Thanks for that. Now, the command behaves completely differently on MacOS (I hear its based on `BSD`) and Ubuntu (`Linux`).   Linux isn't showing any difference in when u `echo` or not. But, MAC OS X is printing as much as the terminal can show. I'm using `iTerm2` and `zsh`. MAC doesn't allow the `--f` option.

Answer (score 0):

The command for MacOS is slightly different
`echo "$(ps aux)"`

Comment: You don't want to pass it through `echo` unnecessarily. Notice also that [several](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358076/117549) [other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229542/117549) answers already mention `ps aux` in some way.  I would suggest comments or edits on those existing answers to point out that they're good for MacOS (which is what I assume you meant).

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do

```
IFS='$';for line in $(ps axf); do echo $line; done
```

Comment: I am curious, why are you setting `IFS` to `$`?